# Angular - Lazy Loading: Module is loading but page is not rendering

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am new at lazy loading on Angular. Module is loading but page is not rendering. I will be so glad if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also I can correct that lazy loading is working when I check the inspect + network.

```
app-routing.module.ts

  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import("../app/components/tasks/tasks.module").then(m => m.TasksModule)},

tasks.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: ListComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'today',
        loadChildren: () => import(`./today-list/today-list.module`)
          .then((mod) => mod.TodayListModule)
      }
    ]
  },
];
imports => RouterModule.forChild(routes),

today-list.module.ts

imports => RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: TodayListComponent }]),


app.component.html

<router-outlet *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"></router-outlet>

<mat-drawer-container class="side-container" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <mat-drawer mode="side" opened class="side-container-left"><app-sidebar></app-sidebar></mat-drawer>
<mat-drawer-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Comment: What exactly is not rendering? The `ListComponent` or the `TodayListComponent`? Can you add the Templates where `router-outlet` tags are set? Can you also add the routerLink you are routing to?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus I edited the first message, there are router-outlet tags. And TodayListComponent is not rendering. The page is not changing, today-list-works! does not appear.

Comment: and where is yours `RouterModule.forRoot` ?

Comment: Is there also a `router-outlet` tag in your `ListComponent`? Child routes in angular define a hierarchical component tree. Angular will try to search in this `ListComponent` for this tag to render children defined in the routes array.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus there is RouterModule.forRoot in app-routing.module.ts.

where will I put router-outlet in ListComponent?

Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: actually I don't know if you even want to have child routes. Because of the question where you should put it, I assume you don't have the need for hierarchical component tree. If you still want to try it, you can put a `router-outlet` somewhere in your `ListComponent`, where your `TodayListComponent` should be rendered.